# Why is menu item for custom module not showing?

Tags: 6, routes

I'm new to Drupal and about to write my first custom module ("configurator") with help of the drupal documentation.

I've implemented the **menu hook**:

```
function configurator_menu()
{
    $items = array();
    $items['configurator'] = array(
        'title' => 'Configurator',
        'page callback' => 'configurator_init',
        'access callback' => TRUE, 
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
     );
     return $items;
}

function configurator_init()
{
    return "<p> Hello World </p>";
}
```

At "Administer > Site Building > Modules" the module is shown and activated. Cache has been cleared, but somehow the menu item for my "configurator" module is not showing up.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've either forgotten to set the `menu_name` key for the menu you want to add the link to:

```
$items['configurator'] = array(
  'title' => 'Configurator',
  'page callback' => 'configurator_init',
  'access callback' => TRUE, 
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'menu_name' => 'primary-links',
);
```

Or you want to use the default ('navigation'), but you're using the wrong type. It should be

```
$items['configurator'] = array(
  'title' => 'Configurator',
  'page callback' => 'configurator_init',
  'access callback' => TRUE, 
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

[`MENU_CALLBACK`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/constant/MENU_CALLBACK/6) is:

> Callbacks simply register a path so that the correct function is fired when the URL is accessed. **They are not shown in the menu.**

Emphasis mine.